# Issue with Webpack 4.1.1 and UglifyJS2 - Production mode mangles code which throws uncaught error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, codemirror, uglifyjs

I've upgraded a project to Webpack 4.1.1 and encountered a bug with UglifyJS that I cant seem to get around.

Minimum reproducible repo here: https://github.com/jamesopti/uglifyjs-webpack-issue

Although I think this is a bug, I'd like to try and configure UglifyJS to work around it. No luck so far despite the options shown below.

```
uglifyOptions: {
  mangle: false,
  keep_classnames: true,
  keep_fnames: true,
},
```

Any ideas?

Main.js code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactCodeMirror from 'react-codemirror';

// Enables syntax highlighting for javascript
require('codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript');
// Enables linting for javascript
require('codemirror/addon/lint/lint');
require('codemirror/addon/lint/javascript-lint');

window.JSHINT = require('jshint').JSHINT;

const defaultOptions = {
  lint: true,
};

render(
  <ReactCodeMirror
    options={defaultOptions}
    value={'some\ncode'}
  />, document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Webpack config:

```js
  entry: './src/main.js',

  mode: 'development',

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ { loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' } ] },
      { test: [/\/src\/(?:.*)\.js$/], use: { loader: 'babel-loader' } },
    ]
  },

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          mangle: false,
          keep_classnames: true,
          keep_fnames: true,
        },
      }),
    ]
  }
```

[image: Error rendering component]

Comment: For me I had this error when I cloned the repo. But I fixed it by installing `babel-loader`, `babel-preset-react`, and `babel-preset-es2015`. And I don't see any errors. I followed the instructions you provided on the repo. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: My apologies! I accidentally checked in a webpack config with `mode: development` from my back and forth verification. I just checked the right production config back in and added the babel dependencies you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this is a bug in UglifyJS (reported [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/265)).

Minimal reproducible code:

```js
(function(mod) {
  mod();
})(function() {
  function getMaxSeverity(ax, bx) {
    if (ax === "error") {
      return ax;
    } else {
      return bx;
    }
  }
  function main() {
    var arr = ['hey'];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      console.log(getMaxSeverity('one', 'two'));
    }
  }
  main();
});
```

The workaround is the compress inline option

```js
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          inline: 1,
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}
```